# Insert blob from android to oracle

Tags: php, android, oracle11g

I'm working with Oracle database. I use PHP for my web service and Android as the client which will send blob data to Oracle DB. I use this code

`Bitmap imageUpload = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            imageUpload.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, baos);
            byte[] image_data = baos.toByteArray();
            String converted_image = Base64.encodeBytes(image_data);`

to decode and send it as base64 encoding, then send it to the web service with this code

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("TITLE", title));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IMAGES", converted_image));
            json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", nameValuePairs);
```

This is my PHP code to insert to oracle db

```
if(isset($_POST["TITLE"]) && isset($_POST["IMAGES"]))
{
    $title = $_POST["TITLE"];
    $image = $_POST["IMAGES"];
    $gambar = file_get_contents($image);

    $query = "INSERT INTO images (TITLE, IMAGES) VALUES (:TITLE, EMPTY_BLOB()) RETURNING IMAGES INTO :IMAGES";
    $parse = oci_parse($connect, $query);

    $lob_a = oci_new_descriptor($connect, OCI_D_LOB);

    oci_bind_by_name($parse, ":TITLE", $title);
    oci_bind_by_name($parse, ":IMAGES", $lob_a, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
    oci_execute($parse, OCI_DEFAULT);

    if($lob_a->save($gambar))
    {
        oci_commit($connect);
        $lob_a->free();
    }
    else
    {
        oci_rollback($connect);
    }
}
```

The PHP code successfully insert the query to the oracle db, but when I see the record the blob does not show anything like this

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution to this question is to use web service, encode the picture with base64 encoding then decode it while the file transferred.